# Construction of a Martingale from a random walk

Tags: martingales

A martingale can be constructed from a random walk. Can someone give a numerical example of how this can be done together with some little proof to spice up the example?

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to get here. A symmetric random walk is already a martingale. Do you want to know how to construct a martingale from an asymmetric random walk? (One way to do it is to subtract off the effective drift: if a walk goes to the right with probability $0.5+\delta$, then its effective drift is $2\delta$ per time step. Thus if $X_n$ is a random walk which goes to the right with probability $0.5+\delta$, then $X_n-2\delta n$ is a martingale.)

Comment: Thanks @Ian for this contribution